# Нарисовать внутри Rectangle прямую линию. C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Всем привет. Как нарисовать внутри объекта [Rectangle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) прямую линию? Например, [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.stringformat%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) внутри Rectangle (прямоугольника) рисуется следующим образом:

```
StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

Graphics.DrawString("Некий текст", Font,
                     new SolidBrush(ForeColor),
                     rectangle , format);
```

Хочется как-то в этом духе нарисовать прямую линию. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: [Graphics.DrawLine][1] как бы это не показалось странным


  [1]: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/f956fzw1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Graphics.DrawLine рисует линию на заданных координатах. Мне нужно чтобы линия рисовалась именно в области прямоугольника, т.е. если говорить другими словами, область прямоугольника должна быть контейнером для линии. Т.е. как и в моем примере выше, прямоугольник является контейнером для текста.

Comment: В rectangle хранятся координаты прямоугольника. Надо рассчитать середину и нарисовать.

Comment: @sp7, нет такой функции в .net "Нарисовать линию в прямоугольнике". Как правильно заметил @Deadkenny, Вам сначала надо вычислить координаты Вашей линии и уже потом нарисовать ее с помощью `DrawLine`

Comment: Понятно, спасибо, искал что-то стандартное. Не хотелось если честно заморачиваться с координатами.

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартный способ ограничить регион отрисовки чего угодно на Graphics - [`Graphics.SetClip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.setclip(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    var rectangle = new Rectangle(0, 0, 100, 100);
    StringFormat format = new StringFormat();
    format.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
    format.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;

    e.Graphics.DrawString("Некий текст", Font,
                         new SolidBrush(ForeColor),
                         rectangle, format);

    e.Graphics.SetClip(rectangle);
    // будет обрезано рамкой 100x100
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Red, 0, 0, 200, 200); 
}
```